# apply init_val template to the uint64_attr

Tags: simics, dml-lang

​Hi all,

I want to apply the init_val template to several attributes in my model to reset them by sreset template.

Attribute definition below can't be compiled by 166 base, any suggestions?

```
attribute attr1[10] is (uint64_attr, init_val) {
    param init_val = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`init_val` is a template meant to be applied on registers or fields, not generic attributes (in addition, for registers and fields the template is implicitly provided by the object template and there is no need to explicitly instantiate it)

That said, `uint64_attr` does provide you with an overrideable `init_val` parameter as well, just disconnected from the `init_val` template. So in your case just removing the `init_val` instantiation should make the code compile.

However, this will not be enough to tie the attributes into the soft reset mechanisms. The recommended way to do that would be to instantiate `soft_reset` template in each attribute, and override the `soft_reset` method and have it call into `init`. This should make the attributes re-run their init code (which, if you have not modified it, will set their values to `init_val`).

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do a `hard_reset` and not `soft_reset`. Because `soft_reset` will not reset it to `init_val` but instead to a predefined `soft_reset_val`

According to Simics documentation:

> 5.2.1 soft_reset_val
> 5.2.1.1 Description
>
> Implemented on a register or field. Upon soft reset, the reset value
> is defined by the required soft_reset_val parameter, instead of the
> default init_val.

Comment: This is incorrect on two fronts:
1. This concerns an attribute, not a register or field. The `soft_reset` and `hard_reset` templates can be instantiated for an attribute, but the behavior of resetting to `init_val` must be implemented manually, unlike for registers and fields.
2. That `soft_reset` resets to `soft_reset_val` is correct _only if the `soft_reset_val` template is instantiated_. The `soft_reset_val` template is separate from `soft_reset`. By default, registers and fields soft reset to `init_val` just like for `hard_reset`